# How to return instance of struct, idiomatic way

Tags: go

I've got function that returns struct instance depending on argument it takes

```
func Factory(s string) interface{} {
    if s == 'SomeType' {
        return SomeType{}
    } else if s == 'AnotherType' {
        return AnotherType{}
    }
}
```

this solution is good if I have a couple of structs to return but it's getting ugly if there are a lot of them, can I do it other way? Is there idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: You can use a map to map the string to what you want to return. Or if it's more complicated than returning an empty struct, the map can map the string to a function that produces the value.

Comment: I didn’t down vote. It’s not uncommon for someone to just give guidance as opposed to giving a full solution.

Comment: @AndySchweig I'm very sorry for that comment but sometimes I didn't understand why here people downvoting I can't find any logic in their behavior. I think mapping to function is what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment said, you can use a map for your types. Looks like this. The factory function will return an instance if the type exists or nil if it doesn't.
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type SomeType struct{ Something string }
type AnotherType struct{}
type YetAnotherType struct{}

var typemap = map[string]interface{}{
    "SomeType":       SomeType{ Something: "something" },
    "AnotherType":    AnotherType{},
    "YetAnotherType": YetAnotherType{},
}

func factory(s string) interface{} {
    t, ok := typemap[s]
    if ok {
        return reflect.ValueOf(t)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", factory("SomeType"))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", factory("NoType"))
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/uyOLkG4RTRb)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mad-wombat but isn't it returning the same instance every time I'm calling `factory`?

Comment: Yes, it would. Sorry. You can use reflect to create a new value every time. Updated the code and link

Comment: Actually, updated again, looks like using ValueOf() instead of New() provides a bit more flexibility. You can do initialization in your map and it will be preserved.

Comment: looks promising will try it tomorrow.